# How to turn on the spot

Tags: dragon-fin-soup

In dragon fin soup sometimes you'll want to turn on the spot without using a turn. I seem to recall it was in the tutorial but now can't remember how on earth I did it!

Can anyone remind me of this most basic of moves?

Answer (score 1):

Accidently found this myself while playing.

Right stick allows you to turn on the spot without using up a turn.